# How to approximate $\exp(-t(A-B))$ for diagonal $A$ and rank-1 $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

I have $d\times d$ diagonal matrix $A=\operatorname{diag}a$ and rank-1  $B=b b^T$ and need to efficiently approximate the following function:
$$f(t)=\langle\exp(-t(A-B))\rangle$$

Here $\langle M \rangle$ represents the sum of all entries in matrix $M$ and $0<t<d^2$. In my application, $a=2b(1-b)$ and $b$ is some vector of positive numbers adding up to 1.

My original [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/282497/) of $f(t)\approx \langle\exp(-t A)\rangle$ was not accurate enough. Any advice what expansion I should use here?

Comment: what are you averaging over?

Comment: clarified the meaning of $\langle M\rangle$, not sure if there's standard notation for "sum of all entries of the matrix"

Comment: How large is $d$?

Comment: This question is about math, not physics.

Comment: If $b\in R^n$ is a column vector, what do you mean by the square matrix $A=b(1-b)?$

Comment: $a=2b(1-b)$ is another vector, and $A=\operatorname{diag}a$ is a diagonal matrix with entries of $a$ on diagonal

Answer (score 2):

It’s not super clear what you’re trying to do but you can use the [Zassenhaus formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Zassenhaus_formula) will give
$$
e^{-t(A-B)}\approx e^{-tA} e^{tB} e^{t^2[A,B]}\ldots
$$
There is obviously further simplification if $[A,B]=0$ or if $[A,[A,B]]=0$ or $[B,[A,B]]=0$ but that’s not clear if this is your case.

The link gives terms up to $t^4$ but [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.04681#) gives a systematic way of finding even higher order corrections.

Finally, the paper by

> Casas, F., Murua, A., & Nadinic, M. (2012). Efficient computation of the Zassenhaus formula. Computer Physics Communications, 183(11), 2386-2391.

promises an efficient numerical implementation to compute higher order terms.

Comment: Aha, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Wondering if anything is known about when truncating this expansion gives good approximation....it appears to not converge very fast for the matrices in question